# Releasing an iOS app for one particular device

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

In the Xcode Deployment Info it is possible to set Devices to iPad/iPhone/Universal. However, is it possible to somehow configure the app so that it can be installed only on one particular device type (like iPad Pro for example)?

Comment: No, you can only set hardware requirements. Read the [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1397/_index.html) for more. Here is a list of the available options: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

Answer (score 1):

When trying to archive your app build, you can able to see the options only for **Save to Ad Hoc Deployment & Save for Development Deployment**.

> Not for Distribution in App store(Save for iOS App Store Deployment)

1. Export one app for all compatible devices
2. Export for specific devices
   [image]